# Skypekit C++ How to get each contact avatar?

Tags: c#, wpf, web-services, skype, skype4com

I am new to skype development. I want to build a application that allow user to login by skype account. I can do the login with skypekit c++ and I also list all the contact name with status. But I want to show the contact's avatar of each contact.

Please show me step by step...

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

`bool Contact`::[GetAvatar](http://developer.skype.com/skypekit/reference/cpp/class_contact.html#aa29bf3411b6a6f90e1f920817a7228c9)`(bool &present, Sid::Binary &avatar)`

Returns Conrtact's avatar image (JPG).

`avatar` The avatar image data (JPG). If present is false, this will be the Skype-assigned default avatar.

- request an avatar
- write it to a file.jpg
- do whatever you want with that file